# What does this block of SAS code do?

Tags: sas, pseudocode

I have sas code that I need to partially convert to c++ code, however I am struggling understand its function. I have no experience with sas, and after a few hours of various tutorials and examples I have made very little progress. I don't have access to any of the input data or any corresponding output either. The code follows the following format, but I've changed the variable names:

```
data data1;
set data2;
output;

if type='ABCD' and zone=1 then do;
    type='BCDE'; spec='CDE'; sub='ABCD DEF'; output;
    type='EFGH'; spec='FGH'; output;
    type='ABCD'; spec='DEF';
end;
```

The code then continues on, however I only need to understand the logic of this if statement. In the actual code there are many of these statements but they all follow the same structure, understanding one should help me to understand them all. The variable values are only important insofar as type and uniqueness, if variables here share a value then that is true in the original code as well, otherwise they are different.

I know that the program is designed to take combinations of type/spec/zone and convert them into other type/spec combinations but I can't seem to grasp the logic.

Comment: IF statements are the same in pretty much all languages. The only different thing in this is the OUTPUT. OUTPUT causes an explicit WRITE to occur. Since this step has OUTPUT you don't need to worry about data step boundaries. What's happening here is duplicating the record and creating a different type/spec for each record so you should end up with records X 3 for each record that meets the IF condition.

Comment: @Reeza so if I understand correctly, for every record in the input data it finds that has type 'ABCD' and zone 1, it will copy the record and replace its type with 'BCDE', spec with 'CDE', and sub with 'ABCD DEF' then write the record to the output data. repeat this with the next line, now what about the third line? it doesn't output, does the same thing happen?

Comment: I suspect there's another OUTPUT somewhere later in your code that you haven't shown.

Comment: Hmm... so in the actual code this if/end statement is followed by 17 more, and in all of them they have the same structure where the last line is not followed by an output. The first output that follows the if/end statements comes after DATA and SET statements.
I don't think the particulars of that one line are all that important. I appreciate your help! You certainly got me on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DATA and SET statements define the target and source, respectively.

The first OUTPUT statement will insure that the target has at least one copy of every record read from the source data.

The code inside the DO END block of the IF/THEN statement will cause two additional records to be written when it runs. They will have different values for the TYPE, SPEC and SUB variables as the assignment statements indicate. At the end of the DO block the values of TYPE, SPEC and SUB will have been set to  'ABCD','DEF' and 'ABCD DEF', respectively.

So if your input is

```
TYPE,SPEC,SUB,ZONE
ABCD,UNK,UNK,0
ABCD,XX,YY,1
UNK,UNK,UNK,0
```

The values written by the part of the code you posted would be.

```
TYPE,SPEC,SUB,ZONE
ABCD,UNK,UNK,0
ABCD,XX,YY,1
BCDE,CDE,ABCD DEF,1
EFGH,FGH,ABCD DEF,1
UNK,UNK,UNK,0
```

Comment: Thanks! Showing the input/corresponding output was very helpful. I can understand what the rest of my code is doing following the same logic as well. I modified the question a bit so that I could accept your answer.